# Converting Points to Line Feature in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3

I am writing to ask if there is the possibility to use extensions written for ArcView 3.2 in ArcGIS 9.3

With the older version of the gis package, i had an extension that allowed me to link together isolated points, in a large pool of coordinates, with the same attributes into a line.

A typical example of my data is:

- 10 hours of navigation at sea made in 2 days resulting in, say, 1000 stored coordinates (500/day)
- the daily navigation can be defined in different ways depending on the sea state (beaufort and duglas scales), weather condition, visibility and so on; my categories are, say, negative navigation "NN", positive navigation "PN" and off effort "X" (no navigation or transfer from a sector to another)
- within the same day i can have all the three categories of navigation mentioned above, say in the following order: X, NN, PN, X, PN, X, NN, X
- all the info about the navigation are stored in a single *.txt tab delimited file

What I need, after importing and playing with the *.txt file in arcgis9.3, is a tool/extension that allows me to create a line, starting from the single points/coordinates, using those points/coordinates with the same attributes. say that i want to create a line that links those points that have the following characteristics: day, navigation status, beaufort scale, douglas scale, weather condition and visibility. if there is a series of 100 consecutive points with these characteristics they should be part of the same line. as soon as the next points, say, from 101 to 200 have at least one different value of the above attributes, they should be linked among them but not with the previous 100. basically, the final result should be a series of consecutive lines which i can know the attributes and the length.

I could do all these things in ArcView 3.2 using a dedicated extension (i did not write it).

How can i do the same things in ArcGIS Desktop 9.3?

Answer (score 3):

I have created a [script](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15828) for ArcGIS 9.3 that uses a point dataset to create a polyline dataset with the points' attributes. The tool allows a user to select a field name from the points layer to group the line segments, a field name to sort the groups (optional), and the point layer fields to be copied to the line layer. Line segments are created from two points with the same attribute in the group field. The attributes for the line segment are taken from the first point. The points DO NOT have to be sorted by group attribute and order.

The points can be grouped by numeric, string, or date fields and can be sorted by numeric or date fields. Point datasets stored in SDE geodatabases cannot be grouped by a date field, but can be sorted by a date field.

Answer (score 2):

**ET GeoWizards**

http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/gw_NoRestrictions.htm

Point To Polyline

If you purchase the software the source code is available

Answer (score 1):

Direct porting from 3.2 to 9.3 would not be possible as a lot has changed since then.

You can however, write a custom code to achieve your result, that is very much possible. This will require sufficient understanding of ArcObjects (AO) programming.

If you're not that proficient with AO, you can perhaps ask somebody to write it for you.

Answer (score 1):

This ArcObjects script below will create a line shp between records stored in a dbf that have the same attribute values.  It is a bit lengthy, but does the trick.  To run it the dbf needs an ID field, and both X and Y fields (update the code to match your field names).

You could assign the code below to a UIControl (button).  The link below will show you how to create a UI Control in ArcMap.

[Creating custom commands with VBA and UI Controls](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Creating_custom_commands_with_VBA_and_UI_Controls)

```
Public Sub ConnectPointFeatures()
'----- open the table -----
  Dim pWorkspaceFactoryTable As IWorkspaceFactory
  Set pWorkspaceFactoryTable = New ShapefileWorkspaceFactory
  Dim pWorkspaceTable As IWorkspace
  Dim pFWSTable As IFeatureWorkspace
  Dim path As String
  path = "C:\Temp"
  Set pWorkspaceTable = pWorkspaceFactoryTable.OpenFromFile(path, 0)
  Dim pTable As ITable
  Set pFWSTable = pWorkspaceTable
  Dim xtable As String
  xtable = "Connect dots.dbf"
  Set pTable = pFWSTable.OpenTable(xtable)

  Dim ID_in_index As Integer
  Dim ID_in_type As String
  Dim pFields As IFields
  Dim pField As IField
  Set pFields = pTable.Fields
  ID_in_index = pFields.FindField("APPNO")
  Set pField = pFields.field(ID_in_index)
  ID_in_type = pField.Type

  '***** create shapefile function -- do it here to generate correct ID field type
  CreateShapefile (ID_in_type)
  '***** create shapefile function *****

  '----- set up table and table properties to read -----
  Dim pCursor As ICursor
  Dim pQueryFilter As IQueryFilter2
  Set pQueryFilter = New QueryFilter
  If ID_in_type >= 0 And ID_in_type < 4 Then pQueryFilter.WhereClause = "POINT_X" & " <> 0 AND " & "POINT_Y" & " <> 0 AND " & "APPNO" & " >= 0"
  If ID_in_type = 4 Then pQueryFilter.WhereClause = "APPNO" & " <> ''"
  If ID_in_type > 4 Then
    MsgBox ("ID field type not supported --> Processing terminated.")
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Set pCursor = pTable.Search(pQueryFilter, True)
  Dim pRow As IRow
  Dim RowCounter As Long
  Dim RowCount As Long
  RowCount = pTable.RowCount(pQueryFilter)

  ''''''''''''''''''''''''
  Dim pWorkspaceFactory As IWorkspaceFactory
  Dim pWorkSpace As IWorkspace
  Dim pFWS As IFeatureWorkspace
  Set pWorkspaceFactory = New ShapefileWorkspaceFactory
  Set pFWS = pWorkspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(tbOutputPath, 0)
  Dim pFeatureClass As IFeatureClass
  Set pFeatureClass = pFWS.OpenFeatureClass(tbOutputFile)
  Dim pDataset As IDataset
  Set pDataset = pFeatureClass
  Dim ID_out_index As Variant
  ID_out_index = pFeatureClass.FindField("APPNO")

  '----- create variables to store X Y & IDs -----
  Dim xVal As Double
  Dim yVal As Double
  Dim xVal2 As Double
  Dim yVal2 As Double
  Dim rowID As Variant
  Dim rowID2 As Variant

  '----- get field indexes for fields to read from -----
  Dim Xindex As Integer
  Dim Yindex As Integer
  Dim IDindex As Integer
  Xindex = pTable.FindField("POINT_X")
  Yindex = pTable.FindField("POINT_Y")
  IDindex = pTable.FindField("APPNO")

  '----- create variables to generate a new feature and populate fields-----
  Dim pGeomColl As IGeometryCollection
  Dim pSegColl As ISegmentCollection
  Dim pLine As ILine, pPolyline As IPolyline
  Dim pFeature As IFeature
  Set pSegColl = New path

  '***** DO IT *****

  '----- if merging by segment IDs -----
    fol = "C:\Temp"
   'change to match the folder path
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   If fso.FolderExists(fol) Then
  'If cbMergebyID.Value = False Then

    '--- get first row ---
    Set pRow = pCursor.NextRow
    xVal = pRow.value(Xindex)
    yVal = pRow.value(Yindex)
    rowID = pRow.value(IDindex)
    '--- get second row ---
    Set pRow = pCursor.NextRow
    xVal2 = pRow.value(Xindex)
    yVal2 = pRow.value(Yindex)
    rowID2 = pRow.value(IDindex)
    '--- if second is same ID as first then start the feature ---
    If rowID2 = rowID Then
      Set pLine = CreateLn(CreatePt(xVal, yVal), CreatePt(xVal2, yVal2))
      Set pSegColl = New path
      pSegColl.AddSegment pLine
    End If
    '--- assign second row to fnode position ---
    xVal = xVal2
    yVal = yVal2
    'zVal = zVal2
    rowID = rowID2

    Set pRow = pCursor.NextRow
    RowCounter = 2
    Do Until pRow Is Nothing
      RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
      frmPoints2Lines.Caption = "Processing " & RowCounter & " of " & RowCount & " total points."

      xVal2 = pRow.value(Xindex)
      yVal2 = pRow.value(Yindex)
      rowID2 = pRow.value(IDindex)

      '--- if next row has same id then add a line segment to seg collection ---
      If rowID2 = rowID Then
        Set pLine = CreateLn(CreatePt(xVal, yVal), CreatePt(xVal2, yVal2))
        pSegColl.AddSegment pLine
        '--- otherwise, if seg collection has any segs then make a polyline ---
      ElseIf pSegColl.SegmentCount > 0 Then
        Set pGeomColl = New Polyline
        pGeomColl.AddGeometry pSegColl
        Set pFeature = pFeatureClass.CreateFeature
        Set pPolyline = pGeomColl
        Set pFeature.Shape = pPolyline
        pFeature.value(ID_out_index) = rowID
        pFeature.Store
        pSegColl.RemoveSegments 0, pSegColl.SegmentCount, False
      End If

      '--- backcalculate to-pt to from-pt
      xVal = xVal2
      yVal = yVal2
      'zVal = zVal2
      rowID = rowID2
      Set pRow = pCursor.NextRow
    Loop

    '--- deal with last line of file ---
    If rowID = rowID2 Then
      Set pGeomColl = New Polyline
      pGeomColl.AddGeometry pSegColl
      Set pFeature = pFeatureClass.CreateFeature
      Set pPolyline = pGeomColl
      Set pFeature.Shape = pPolyline
      pFeature.value(ID_out_index) = rowID
      pFeature.Store
    End If

  '----- if NOT merging by segment IDs -----
  'ElseIf cbMergebyID.Value = False Then
  Else
    '--- get first row ---
    Set pRow = pCursor.NextRow
    xVal = pRow.value(Xindex)
    yVal = pRow.value(Yindex)
    rowID = pRow.value(IDindex)

    Set pRow = pCursor.NextRow
    RowCounter = 2
    Do Until pRow Is Nothing
      RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
      frmPoints2Lines.Caption = "Processing " & RowCounter & " of " & RowCount & " total points."

      xVal2 = pRow.value(Xindex)
      yVal2 = pRow.value(Yindex)
      rowID2 = pRow.value(IDindex)

      '--- if next row has same id then add a line segment to seg collection ---
      If rowID2 = rowID Then
        Set pLine = CreateLn(CreatePt(xVal, yVal), CreatePt(xVal2, yVal2))
        Set pSegColl = New path
        pSegColl.AddSegment pLine
        Set pGeomColl = New Polyline
        pGeomColl.AddGeometry pSegColl
        Set pFeature = pFeatureClass.CreateFeature
        Set pPolyline = pGeomColl
        Set pFeature.Shape = pPolyline
        pFeature.value(ID_out_index) = rowID
        pFeature.Store
      End If
      xVal = xVal2
      yVal = yVal2
      rowID = rowID2
      Set pRow = pCursor.NextRow
    Loop

  End If

End Sub

Private Function CreateShapefile(ByVal ID_in_type As String)

'----- delete if shapefile already exists -----
Dim pFWS As IFeatureWorkspace
Dim pWorkspaceFactory As IWorkspaceFactory
Set pWorkspaceFactory = New ShapefileWorkspaceFactory
'Dim tbOutputPath As String
tbOutputPath = "C:\Temp"
'Dim tbOutputFile As String
tbOutputFile = "Line"
Set pFWS = pWorkspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(tbOutputPath, 0)
Dim pFeatClass As IFeatureClass
Dim pDataset As IDataset

'----- if shapefile exists then delete -----
Dim pFSO As Object

Set pFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If pFSO.FileExists(tbOutputPath & "\" & tbOutputFile) Then
  Set pFeatClass = pFWS.OpenFeatureClass(tbOutputFile)
   If (Not pFeatClass Is Nothing) Then
    Set pDataset = pFeatClass
    pDataset.Delete
  End If
End If

'----- Set up the shapefile geometry field -----
Dim pFields As IFields
Dim pFieldsEdit As IFieldsEdit
Set pFields = New Fields
Set pFieldsEdit = pFields

Dim pField As IField
Dim pFieldEdit As IFieldEdit
Set pField = New field
Set pFieldEdit = pField
pFieldEdit.name = "Shape"
pFieldEdit.Type = esriFieldTypeGeometry

Dim pGeomDef As IGeometryDef
Dim pGeomDefEdit As IGeometryDefEdit
Set pGeomDef = New GeometryDef
Set pGeomDefEdit = pGeomDef
  With pGeomDefEdit
      .GeometryType = esriGeometryPolyline
      Set .SpatialReference = New UnknownCoordinateSystem
  End With
Set pFieldEdit.GeometryDef = pGeomDef
pFieldsEdit.AddField pField

'----- Add an ID field for relate back to point source field -----
Set pField = New field
Set pFieldEdit = pField

With pFieldEdit
   .name = "APPNO"
   .Type = ID_in_type
End With

pFieldsEdit.AddField pField

'----- Create the shapefile -----
Set pFeatClass = pFWS.CreateFeatureClass(tbOutputFile, pFields, Nothing, Nothing, esriFTSimple, "Shape", "")

End Function

Private Function CreatePt(ByVal dX As Double, _
ByVal dY As Double) As IPoint
Set CreatePt = New Point
CreatePt.PutCoords dX, dY
End Function

Private Function CreateLn(ByRef pPointFrom As IPoint, pPointTo As IPoint) As ILine
Set CreateLn = New Line
CreateLn.PutCoords pPointFrom, pPointTo
End Function
```